# Build successfully for iOS Device But Build Error for iOS Simulator (Get other linker flag error)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, ios-simulator

I have been facing this lingering issue. When I try to Build the project by selecting iOS device in my Xcode it builds the code with out any error but when I trying the same with iOS simulator it shows me the following error.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-ClientService
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: There are few libraries that only run on devices that cant be run on simulator they require arm7 processor .If you provide the list of libraries you used it will help us to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to use a library that you created yourself or downloaded from a 3rd party with your product, and the linker either not find it, or it does not contain a valid slice for the architecture / platform that you are trying to link.

It is most likely that the library is just an arm library, without an intel slice.

If you are building it yourself, this may be because the library and your app are in two separate Xcode projects.  If you integrate them into a single project, the build system should take care of making sure that the library gets built for the correct platform and architecture(s) when building your app.